# Javascript singleton: How to access private variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, singleton

I have this singleton. The public functions allow to set private variables but I am not able to set them in the way that I am able to use them in the private methods:

```
var ServiceInterface = (function () {
  // Instance stores a reference to the Singleton
  var instance;

  function init() {
    // Singleton
    // Private methods and variables
    var m_action;

    function performAction() {
      alert(m_action);
    }

    return {
      // Public methods and variables
      callBackend: function (sAction) {
        m_action = sAction;
      }
    };
  };
})
```

`m_action` is not available throughout the public and private section of the singleton. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you trying to access m_action (more where are you calling performAction).

Comment: For what purpose do you need to use this concept of private fields with public accessors?

Comment: @scunliffe he return an object, it's ok.

Comment: Is this all your code? Because as it's set up, nothing ever happens. The outer most function (`ServiceInterface = (function () {`) is never called and thus is simply stored in `ServiceInterface`. And even if it were called, `init` then is never called and is not accessible from *the outside*, so absolutely nothing happens inside the function!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're referring to this

```
var ServiceInterface = (function () {
    var m_action;

    function performAction() {
      alert(m_action);
    }

    return {
      // Public methods and variables
      callBackend: function (sAction) {
        m_action = sAction;
        performAction();
      }
    };
})()

ServiceInterface.callBackend("Hello world");
```

You need to execute anonymous function. Running it enables to create variables and functions defined with the anonymous function and these cannot be seen outside. Most of js libraries use this convention to create modules and to avoid infecting the global scope

```
var ServiceInterface = (function () {
   // code inside 
})()
```

These are the variables and functions confined within the scope of anonymous function executed

```
// var ServiceInterface = (function () {
    var m_action;

    function performAction() {
      alert(m_action);
    }

// })()
```

Finally, return a javascript object that will expose functions that can be accessible outside the anonymous function scope

```
//var ServiceInterface = (function () {
//  var m_action;
//    
//  function performAction() {
//       alert(m_action);
//  }

    return {
      // Public methods and variables
      callBackend: function (sAction) {
        m_action = sAction;
        performAction();
      }
    };
//})()
```

However, why go through the trouble of making private variable and method for a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create a singleton with a private member variable.

```
ServiceInterface = new (function() {
    var m_action = false;

    this.setAction = function(s) {
        m_action = s;
    };
    this.getAction = function() {
        return m_action;
    };

    this.performAction = function() {
        alert(ServiceInterface.getAction());
    };

    this.createCallback = function() {
        return function(sAction) {
            ServiceInterface.setAction(sAction);
        };
    }
})();
ServiceInterface.setAction("secret");
ServiceInterface.performAction();
```

`ServiceInterface` becomes a singleton because the constructor function is thrown away after it's created. `ServiceInterface = new (.....)();` is how it's executed right after being declared. It's a singleton because there is no way for someone to create another instance.

I don't use `var` to create the instance. When you exclude `var` and you're not inside a function the new variable will be attached to the prototype of the parent object. In the browser this will be `window`. `window` is like a global singleton in javascript.

The local variable `m_action` is persisted because `setAction` and `getAction` reference it as closure functions, and the variable is attached to their scope. So they can be used as setter/getter methods.

You can now use `ServiceInterface.setAction(sAction);` in your callbacks to set the private member.

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/w7DdE/6/